# Python list.__iadd__ will take a str as argument

Tags: python, list, cpython

I just by accident found this out:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l + 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
>>> l += 'a'
>>> l
['a']
>>> l + 'abcd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
>>> l += 'abcd'
>>> l
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Is this expected behaviour? I can't find an explanation for this anywhere, and it seems really weird to me

Now testing further...

```
>>> l += 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This led me to believe that `str` only works because it is an iterable, so I tried:

```
>>> class Test:
...     l = [1, 2, 3]
...     
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for i in self.l:
...             yield i
... 
>>> l += Test()
>>> l
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3]
>>> l + Test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Test") to list
```

Now this seems pretty weird and not very pythonic, I was wondering if this might be a bug, any thoughts?

Comment: "l + 'a'" and "l += 'a'" is not some.

Comment: `lst += Y` means "add all of iterable Y to list lst". A string is iterable, so it's completely valid. `X + Y` is less accepting, because the return type of `list + str` is ambiguous: did the programmer expect to get a list or a string?